# Layers don't work in an `overlay` picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following two `tikzpicture`, where the second needs the `overlay`. However, with that option, the line drawn from `A` to `C` goes through `B`, despite the `\begin{pgfonlayer}{back}…\end{pgfonlayer}`. What can I do to make the line appear below B (appart from redrawing B after, which is not practical since it has a random xshift and yshift).

[image: minimal example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[draw=red!50,  fill=red!10]   (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node[draw=green!50,fill=green!10] (B) at (1,0) {B};
  \node[draw=blue!50, fill=blue!10]  (C) at (2,0) {C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}
    \draw (A) -- (C);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A more complete example justifying the use of `remember picture` and `overlay`:

[image: Complete example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,trees}
\pgfdeclarelayer{back}
\pgfsetlayers{back,main}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \matrix[matrix of nodes, every node/.style={anchor=center}] {
      \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below, every node/.style={on chain}]
        \node[draw=red!50,  fill=red!10]   (A1) {A};
        \node[draw=red!50,  fill=red!10]   (A2) {AA};
        \node[draw=red!50,  fill=red!10]   (A3) {AAA};
      \end{tikzpicture} &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[grow cyclic, sibling angle=360/7, edge from parent/.style={draw=none}]
        \node {} child foreach \i in {1,...,7} {
          node[draw=green!50,fill=green!10] {B\i};
        };
      \end{tikzpicture} &
      \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going below, every node/.style={on chain}]
        \node[draw=blue!50, fill=blue!10]  (C1) {C};
        \node[draw=blue!50, fill=blue!10]  (C2) {C};
      \end{tikzpicture} \\
      Label A & Label B & Label C\\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Foo}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{back}
    \draw[thick] (A1) -- (C2);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The layers are local to each picture. In other words: your onlayer statement has no effect; you would need to separate layers inside of a *single* picture.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I'll wait a little to see if someone provides a workaround, otherwise I'll accept your solution. Thanks for the information.